# How to change text to decimal in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, decimal, mysql-workbench

I have plenty of values(previously percentages) of data type text in my MySQL dataset.

They all look like 24.05, 0.25, 46.3, 5.2, etc.

I want to convert these to a data type that will allow me to multiply them later on so that I can make these percentages into complete decimals by multiplying by 0.01.

I've tried

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN col_name binary/decimal/int.
```

I can't figure out how to do this though.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this not work?  alter table table_name modify col_name decimal(5,2)

Comment: @Pankaj That worked! Can I know why you chose 5 for the precision? I know that 2 was for the amount of numbers after the decimal.

Comment: Its just an example, you can choose as per your requirement for precision.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `DECIMAL` datatype.

```
DECIMAL(Precision, Scale)
```

I used the `sakila db` as an example as shown;

```
ALTER TABLE `sakila`.`film` 
CHANGE COLUMN `rental_rate` `rental_rate` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4.99';
```

meaning the rental rate can assume a total of 5 digits. two of them appearing to the right after the decimal point